# Как исправить даблклик во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Существует 3 фрагмента и bottomNavBar. При переходе с фрагмента на фрегмент должен обрабатываться docx файл. все работает, но для обновления textView нужен даблклик на фрагмент home. В идеале все должно обрабатываться при переходе на хоум фрагмент без даблклика.

Home фрагмент

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView textViewMain;
    private TextView fileNameTextView;
    private TextView dataTextView;


    public String filename;
    final String SAVED_TEXTDocx = "SaveTextDocx";
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View homeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        fileNameTextView = homeView.findViewById(R.id.fileNameTextView);
        dataTextView = homeView.findViewById(R.id.dataTextVie);

        textViewMain = homeView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMain);
        progressBar = homeView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        return homeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        //Для сохранения состояния активити
        sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean hasVisited = sPref.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);//Переменная для получения значения первого запуска приложения

        if (!hasVisited) { //Смени на !hasVisited или hasVisited == true
            // выводим нужную активность
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), firstStepActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sPref.edit();
            e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
            e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения

        }
        String savedTextEditTextDocxFile = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXTDocx, "Перейди на сайт и скачай интересующую тебя замену пар");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Получение даты
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-EEEE-yyyy");
        String date = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        dataTextView.setText("Сегодня - " + date);
        MainActivity xxx = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        filename = xxx.textOnWebActivity;

        if (xxx.textOnWebActivity != null)
        {


            filename = xxx.textOnWebActivity;
            System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
            try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename))) {




                // открываем файл и считываем его содержимое в объект XWPFDocument
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("Вижу");
                XWPFDocument docxFile = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fileInputStream));
                XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docxFile);

                // печатаем все содержимое Word файла
                XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docxFile);

                //получаем текст из экстратора

                String DocxText = extractor.getText();

                fileNameTextView.setText(filename);//удаляем все копии знаков боле 1
                DocxText.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\r?\n]]{2,}", " ")
                        .replaceAll("( ?(\r\n)){2,}", "\r\n").replaceAll("( ?\n){2,}", "\n")
                        .replaceAll("^ ", "");



                textViewMain.setText(DocxText);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
                file.delete();
                System.out.println(filename);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textViewMain.setText(savedTextEditTextDocxFile);
        }






        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle inState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(inState);




    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXTDocx, textViewMain.getText().toString());



        ed.commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Естественно все уперлось в жизненный цикл фрагмента, будущим чтецам и искателям - существует метод onResume, который возобновляет работу фрагмента. Извиняюсь за собственную глупость